# How to optimize this SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm working on JSF page which displays components. I would like to aks you how I can optimize this SQL query. I'm at home and I don't have access to Oracle server to test the query:

```
SqlStatementSmall = "SELECT a.* FROM (SELECT b.*, rownum rn "
    + " FROM (select y.name, y.serialnumber, y.location, y.type, y.powerwatt,"
    + " y.dateadded, y.datedeployed, y.weightkg, y.uform, y.zonecage"
    + " FROM component x, componentstats y where x.componentstatsid = y.componentstatsid"
    + " and y.componenttypeid = 1122 ORDER BY %s %s) b"
    + " WHERE rownum <= ?) a" 
    + " WHERE rn > ?";
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes you do. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4 :)

Comment: I added ORDER BY to the SQL query - is this proper way to use it?

Comment: @user1285928 . . . No.  ORDER BY only belongs at the end of the query at the outer most level (unless you are using analytic functions).  It should go after the final WHERE clause.

Comment: What is the query plan?  How big are the two tables?  What indexes are involved?  What column(s) do you eventually put in the `ORDER BY` clause?  How long does it take the query to execute?  What is your performance target?  How selective is the `y.componentTypeId = 1122` predicate?  Since you are having the database implement paging, I'm assuming that you are presenting this data directly to users and that users will not, realistically, look at more than the first page or two of results.  Is that a reasonable assumption?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - In this case, the `ORDER BY` on the inner query is necessary to get the pagination to work correctly and consistently.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff would you write your proposal for the query. I will accept it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hello,

```
        select y.name, y.serialnumber, y.location, y.type, y.powerwatt,y.dateadded, y.datedeployed, y.weightkg, y.uform, y.zonecage, rownum rn
        from component x
        inner join componentstats y on x.componentstatsid = y.componentstatsid 
        where y.componenttypeid = 1122
        and rownum <= ?
        and rownum > ?
        ORDER BY %s %s
```

Updated
NOTE: This would not work, please see @Justin Cave comments, thanks

Comment: This won't work.  First, `ROWNUM` is applied before the `ORDER BY`.  So, at best, this will fetch an arbitrary `N` rows and order them.  It will not fetch an arbitrary `N` rows in order.  There is also no guarantee that the result set will be stable.  Additionally, if the second `rownum > ?` predicate's bind variable is anything other than 0, the query will return no data at all.  The predicate `rownum > 1` will never return a row.

Comment: @Justin Cave would you please write your final proposal.

Comment: @user1285928 - The query you posted looks reasonable with no context. I posted a number of questions that I would need answered in order to get the context to determine whether there is a better way of getting the results you are interested in and/or whether there are ways of improving performance. Without answers to those questions, I can't offer much assistance.

Answer (score 1):

It always astonishes me when people try to do query performance tuning without an execution plan and any statistics. The first thing you should do is get an execution plan.